# What does mastering a weapon do?

Tags: brick-force

After a match, I got a notification pop-up that went something like this.

> Your submachine gun mastery has reached level 3.

Okay. That's great. And not really surprising, considering my only usable weapon is an SMG.

What does it mean, though? Does mastering a weapon type have any benefits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just found that information in Brick-Force's train wreck of a shop interface.

Apparently, mastering a weapon type **gives you a discount** on all weapons of the same type in the shop. This is kind of a big deal, since you have to keep buying your weapons if you want something other than the default junk.

Presumably you master weapons by killing lots of dudes with them. You can master everything that's classified as a weapon, including grenades and melee items.

These are all the mastery tiers and their associated discounts; they apply across the board, regardless which in-game currency type you use.

> Level 1: **0%** off
>   Level 2: **3%** off
>   Level 3: **5%** off
>   Level 4: **8%** off
>   Level 5: **15%** off

(Source: [shop interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni1p6.png); lower right corner)